# TypeError: snapShot.data().delete is not a function. (In 'snapShot.data().delete()', 'snapShot.data().delete' is undefined)]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to delete document from the data that I fetched from firestore but I couldn't

**my code:**

```
const DonationList = ({navigation})=>{

    const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
    const donation = db.collection('donations')
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)




    {/*fetch all donation from database*/}
    React.useEffect(()=>{
      
        const fetchData = async()=>{
            try {
                const list=[];
                 await donation
                 .orderBy('submitTime','desc')
                .get()
                .then((querySnapshot)=>{
                    querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
                        const {userId,name, phone,email,items,address,submitTime,time,date,} = doc.data()
                        list.push({
                           id:doc.id,
                           userId,
                            name,
                            phone,
                            email,
                            items,
                            address,
                            submitTime,
                            time,
                            date
                        })
                    })
        
                })
                setUserData(list)
                if(loading){
                    setLoading(false)
                }
            } catch (error) {
                
            }
        }
        fetchData()
    },[])
```

**Delete function**

```
const deleteFireData = (id)=>{
        donation
        .doc(id)
        .delete()
        .then(() =>{
            Alert.alert(
                'Request Rejected',
                'the request been deleted '
            )
        })
        .catch(e => console.log('error'))
    }
```

so when I run my code and I open the lists of data screen to select any data and delete it individually, the code automatically delete the all data without select myself. However, I would really appreciated if anyone could please help me out as I was struggling a lot with this code and thank you in advance

Comment: Try snapShot?.delete() to call the optional callback

Comment: it is not working and it gives me can't find variable snapShot..!

Comment: can you please write the full answer in a code thank you

Comment: It's difficult to tell where your problem lies since I don't know how these were called